# How to get the first letter of each word

Tags: ruby

I am looking to get user input, then for each word input, I want to take the first letter and display it. For example, if a user puts `"Hello there"`, it should return `"Ht"`. I don't want to use `map:chr`. If you use `gsub` or `split` to get the desired outcome, could you explain how it works?

Comment: What did you try so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `map(&:chr)`?  The answer you've accepted as a solution to your problem is pretty much still doing this, anyway -- the only difference is that it's doing the `split` in a separate step, and using `each` instead of `map`; appending to a result array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method I wrote.

```rb
def first_chars
  final_string = ""

  self.split(" ").each do |word|
    final_string += word.chr
  end

  return final_string
end
```

You would use this instead like `"hello world".first_chars`, which would return `hw`.

What this does is: splits the given string, self, by spaces into an array. Then it adds the first letter of that word using the `.chr` method in the `.each` loop, appends that letter to a string that ends up getting returned.

It could be shortened like this:

```rb
def first_chars 
   final_string = ""
   self.split(" ").each { |word| final_string += word.chr }
   return final_string
end
```

Comment: What's with all the instance variables?

Comment: Compulsive habit with writing them. I'm currently programming a database that has to use a ton...

Comment: This answer's code has an unneeded complexity. Maybe that's the reason of the downvotes.

Comment: Don't stress out about it. While we all appreciate your contributions, this use of instance variables isn't really appropriate and ends up promoting bad habits. Instead of taking the feedback so negatively, take it into account and become a better programmer. One of the true strengths of Ruby is how little you have to do to get the right outcome. In this case: `string.split(" ").map(&:chr).join("")` is enough. Your solution works, but could be a lot more minimal, like omitting `return` and using `map` instead of `each`. Always use `map` when you want to *return* something from each element.

Comment: The solution here using `chr` is actually more minimal than the others and avoids falling into the regular expression trap, but this is lost in the other stuff going on which makes it seem way more complicated and verbose. There's an elegant solution here if you remove all the chaff.

Comment: This is really unidiomatic. You should not use this code, every other answer is much more idiomatic Ruby. "code that actually does the task" is very low bar to judge answers; you should write *good code* in the style of the language. `string.split(/\w/).map { |word| word[0] }.join` or some other version of `split`/`map`/join` is how you should write this in Ruby, not by creating an accumulator and adding onto it, and definitely not with `@` variables which you should use when you actually need them, not arbitrarily.

Comment: Your attitude is childish and most importantly, is not in your own best interest. If you can't take criticism you cannot hope to improve the quality of your code. What you should be  doing is reviewing the comments carefully and editing your answer to incorporate the better ones. If you wish to thank the author of the comment do so in a comment. While writing this I see you've edited your answer. Good, but you've only added to what you had before. It would more helpful to readers if you completely rewrote your answer, presenting only what you now regard as your best advice.

Comment: Here are some points and suggestions about your edit. 1. You need to enclose the string method within `class String ... end`. 2. `.self` is not needed, but does no harm. 3. `split` without an argument is the same as `split(/\s+/)`, which is preferred to `split(' ')` because it splits on one or more contiguous spaces. (cont.)

Comment: ...4. The keyword `return` is not needed (without `return` the value of the last statement executed--here `final_string`-- is returned).  5. It is more idiomatic to write `split.each_with_object('') do |word, final_string|...`, allowing you to remove `final_string = ''` and `final_string` at the end.

Comment: Sorry about my childish attitude.

Comment: It gave me no joy to use those words, but I thought it was something you needed to hear. To learn we all need to be open to criticism, in fact, to seek it. People are here to help, and most believe we can be most useful by being direct and not mincing words. Members have collectively devoted considerable time writing comments on your question. Their motivation certainly was not to put you down. Even if you don't see it that way, the bottom line is that you can learn something from each of those comments.

Comment: I see my error in perspective and I have adjusted it.

Comment: I'd recommend also removing al the instance variables from the "old" answer. The code works perfectly fine without them. This doesn't change the concept of the answer, but removes the bad habits this answer might introduce to people who don't exactly know what they're doing.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure why you don't want to use `map(&:chr)`, but here's a solution without it:

```
def first_chars(string)
  string                     # e.g. "Hello world"
    .split(' ')              # converts it to ["Hello", "world"]
    .map { |word| word[0] }  # converts it to ["H", "w"] (You could also use map(&:chr) here.)
    .join                    # converts it to "Hw"
end

first_chars("Hello world")   #=> "Hw"
```

The key parts to understand here are:

- `split` takes a `String` and converts it to an **`Array` (list) of `String`s**.
- `map` loops through the `Array`, and converts each item by the specified operation. (In this case, taking only the first letter.)
- `join` merges the `Array` back into a single `String`.

Comment: Alternatively, `.map { |word| word[0] }` could be replaced with `.map(&:first)`. The split parameter could also be left out, if `$;` is not set split will default to whitespace.

Comment: @3limin4t0r `String#first` is an ActiveSupport method; not vanilla ruby. You're right about `split`, but I prefer to be explicit.

Answer (score 5):

```
puts "Oh, happy   day".gsub(/ |(?<=\S)./, '')
  #=> "Ohd"
```

The regular expression reads, "match a space or (`|`) match any character (`.`) preceded by any character that is not whitespace (`\S`), `(?<=\S)` being a *positive lookbehind*.

Answer (score 2):

```
gets.gsub(/(?<=\S)\S+\s*/, "")
```